# Heroku - deployment of Django application

Tags: django, heroku

I have application which is running locally.
It is running fine with gunicorn and I am able to start heroku local.
My file structure:
[image: File Structure]

My Procfile:

```
web: PYTHONPATH=`pwd`/.. gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 smartlogisticsserver.wsgi:application
```

Error message from Heroku build on server:

> App not compatible with buildpack:
>   https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
>          More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure  ! 
>   Push failed

Pipefile:

```
[[[source]]

url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"


[requires]

python_version = "3.6"


[packages]

"psycopg2-binary" = "*"
django-heroku = "*"
gunicorn = "*"


[dev-packages]
```

and requirements.txt

```
aiohttp==3.2.0
alembic==0.9.9
async-timeout==3.0.0
attrs==18.1.0
awsebcli==3.12.4
blessed==1.14.2
botocore==1.10.12
cement==2.10.12
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
clients==0.5
colorama==0.3.9
defusedxml==0.5.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.0.5
django-grappelli==2.11.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
dockerpty==0.4.1
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.14
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Admin==1.5.1
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-Migrate==2.1.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
gunicorn==19.8.1
home==0.3.4
idna==2.6
idna-ssl==1.0.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
jmespath==0.9.3
Mako==1.0.7
MarkupSafe==1.0
multidict==4.2.0
oauthlib==2.0.7
pathspec==0.5.6
psycopg2==2.7.4
psycopg2-binary==2.7.4
PyJWT==1.6.1
pyserial==3.4
python-dateutil==2.7.2
python-editor==1.0.3
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2018.4
PyYAML==3.12
redis==2.10.6
requests==2.18.4
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
rfxcom==0.5.0
semantic-version==2.5.0
simplejson==3.14.0
six==1.11.0
social-auth-app-django==2.1.0
social-auth-core==1.7.0
SQLAlchemy==1.2.7
tabulate==0.8.2
termcolor==1.1.0
urllib3==1.22
uWSGI==2.0.17
wcwidth==0.1.7
websocket-client==0.47.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
whitenoise==3.3.1
WTForms==2.1
yarl==1.2.2
```

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: A few side notes: You should use `requirements.txt` (and therefore `pip`) _or_ `Pipfile` / `Pipfile.lock` (and therefore `pipenv`), not both. If both are present `pipenv` will normally be used, but here your files are misnamed: `Pipefile` and `Pipefile.lock` both have an extra "e" in the middle. You can probably delete them.

Answer (score 0):

My files were not sync with GitHub and therefor not deployed properly.